# PostgreSQL / pgAdmin4 Error al posicionarme en el nodo view

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, netbeans-11

estoy programando un base de datos para un sistema de costos industriales, todo marcha bien, pero desde hace un para de días tengo un problema con la misma. El punto es que al pararme sobe el nodo de "vistas" teniendo el panel "SQL" seleccionado me aparece el siguiente error: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
"Error obteniendo información - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR" en el titulo y en el cuerpo del mensaje "can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str". Ademas parece no actualizar los contenidos de las vistas guardadas con anterioridad. No he realizado ningún cambio en la base de datos. Cono dato de color puedo decir que lo único que he hecho fue instalar netbeans-11 para probarlo y actualizar el Dbeaver. En este último tampoco aparecen las vistas en el diagrama ER. Parecería ser que están deshabilitadas. Este comportamiento se da para todas la bases de datos que tengo. Necesito poder resolver esta situación a la brevedad. Desde ya mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo problema. Revisando en la página de pgAdmin dicen que la solución estará lista en el release 4.4.13 el 19 de septiembre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mil gracias por responder. Aprecio mucho tu colaboración. Te comento que resolvi el problema haciendo un backup de mis bases de datos, desinstalando el servidor + el pgAdmin y reinstalando nuevamente todo.

Comment: Mil gracias, Saludos cordiales